# How to make a WinForms program wait (eg. for pressing "enter")?

Tags: c#, winforms, wait, enter

I got WinForm Application. I got function in it. And there is a moment in this function, when I want it to stop going forward and wait for user pressing "enter key" .

I look forward maybe some kind of infnite loop, waiting for specific keyboard key pressed?

Also a second little question, are there other ways of stopping function for an amount of time other then System.Threading.Thread.Sleep ?

Comment: This question may make sense for a console application, but how would it apply to a windows app?

Comment: Windows GUI programming is event driven. Respond to an event indicating that a key has been pressed. It sounds as though you've not really grasped the difference between synchronous programming for console apps and event driven GUI programming. You'll need to get on top of that before going much further.

Answer (score 2):

You should override and implement [`ProcessDialogKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processdialogkey(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keys)
{
    if (keys == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // do your stuff
    }

    base.ProcessDialogKey(keys);
}
```

Another option is to create a button, set it as default and `AcceptButton` on the form. The `Click` event handler will be called when pressing Enter.